# Can I solve this graph theory problem with Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Internet browsing I came across this problem, as can be solved using *Mathematica*.

Edit:
**The image says: Place the following numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in the following diagram (all), without repeating any one in each red circle, so that two consecutive numbers can not be connected by the same line.
Below says incorrect solutions.
Below says:
Find all solutions, if more than one.
With mathematica Find a way to travel the circuit from a number "n" any integer**

**the question is how do I transformed this problem in terms that *Mathematica* can solve it?**

**I can not think a code to get started, I am newbie in mathematica but eager to learn**

***edit 2 :The translation fails, should be random numbers in the circles of the triangle, with no two consecutive numbers are together.***

[image]

Comment: I can't read the picture at all. Do you have a larger version?

Comment: The image is unreadable.  Please include the link to the original of whatever you are trying to show.  In addition, please include the code you have tried so far to accomplish your goal.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It seems like "requires the services of a professional consultant" type request.  This site is not a place to ask others to do your work for you.  If there is something specific about *Mathematica* you do not understand, the community would be glad to try to help you.

Comment: There is no correct solution.

Comment: @Karsten7. Don't be too sure about that. Look carefully...

Comment: Since the question remains closed, take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/CemDo9Y.png) (sorry, no time to Git it). Should get you started - no need to pull out heavy GT functions for this, just check possibles. I think something got lost in the translation, and that the ";" vs ":" in the image is no accident - 4 and 5 are allowed to be consecutive, else there is no solution. As for second part of question, I'm guessing you mean a tour visiting all numbers starting from some other? Please clarify that in your OP. In any case, if question is reopened, I'll put the linked stuff as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple brute-force solution for the interpretation of this problem given in the comment by [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher):

```
fun := Abs@Flatten@
  Differences[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}, {#2, #3}, {#2, #4}, {#2, #6},{#2, #5}, {#3, #4}, {#3, #6}, 
   {#3, #7}, {#6, #5}, {#6, #7}, {#4, #6}} /. {{4, 5} -> {0, 2}, {5, 4} -> {0, 2}}, {0, 1}] &

Select[Permutations[Range@7], FreeQ[fun @@ #, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 7, 5, 6, 1, 3}, {2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 1, 6}, 
>  {2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6}, {3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2}, {3, 1, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2}, 
>  {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4, 6}, {3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6}, {6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2}, 
>  {6, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2}, {6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3}, {6, 4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 3}}
> ```

Visualizing these solutions with

```
Grid[Partition[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 
  2 <-> 6, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 7, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 4 <-> 6}, 
 VertexSize -> 0.5, VertexStyle -> Red, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{5, 10}, {4, 8}, {6, 8}, {5, 7.2}, {3, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 6}}, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range@7 -> (Placed[#, {0.55, 0.45}] & /@ #)], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[15, Bold]] & /@ %, 4]]
```

> [image: solutions]

and a visualization of the slots

[image: slots]

---

### Explanation:

First let's give every position a symbol:

[image: Puzzle]

To solve this puzzle we only have to concentrate on the connections, making sure the difference between the two numbers at the end of each line is bigger than 1 (non-consecutive number), except for `{4,5}` and `{5,4}`. The following list contains all connections represented as sublists:

```
{{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {b, f}, {b, e}, {c, d}, {c, f}, {c, g}, {f, e}, 
 {f, g}, {d, f}}
```

Mapping `Differences` over this list calculates the difference between each pair of connected numbers

```
Differences /@ {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {b, f}, {b, e}, {c, d}, {c, f}, {c, g}, {f, e}, {f, g}, {d, f}}
```

> ```
> {{-a+b},{-a+c},{-b+c},{-b+d},{-b+f},{-b+e},{-c+d},{-c+f},{-c+g},{e-f},{-f+g},{-d+f}}
> ```

We'll take care of the exception for `4` and `5` (not being considered as consecutive numbers) by replacing `{4,5}` and `{5,4}` with `{0, 2}` before the differences are calculated. To simplify things the absolute value of the differences is taken. `Abs` automatically threads over list, e.g.,

```
Abs[{{a}, {b}, {c}}]
```

> ```
> {{Abs[a]}, {Abs[b]}, {Abs[c]}}
> ```

Such a nested list can be flattened using

```
% // Flatten
```

> ```
> {Abs[a], Abs[b], Abs[c]}
> ```

Putting it all together into one function:

```
fun2[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_}] := Abs[
 Differences /@ ({{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {b, f}, {b, e}, {c, d}, {c, f}, 
  {c, g}, {f, e}, {f, g}, {d, f}} /. {{4, 5} -> {0, 2}, {5, 4} -> {0, 2}})
 ] // Flatten
```

One can find all possible permutations of the numbers `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` with

```
perms = Permutations[Range@7]
```

Finally, `Select` is used to select all permutation which will result in a list without any `1` after `fun2` is applied to them

```
Select[perms, FreeQ[fun2@#, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 7, 5, 6, 1, 3}, {2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 1, 6}, 
>  {2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6}, {3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2}, {3, 1, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2}, 
>  {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4, 6}, {3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6}, {6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2}, 
>  {6, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2}, {6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3}, {6, 4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 3}}
> ```

Comment: Which number is which? Could you maybe draw one of them in a graph? I thought they were top-to-bottom, left-to-right, but then 4,5 in the first example would be neighbors.

Comment: @nikie They are top-to-bottom, left-to-right, and you are right 4 & 5 are neighbors in all solutions.  As [rasher](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) interprets this puzzle, 4 & 5 are allowed to be neighbors. Otherwise there is no solution.

Comment: I see. The solution got lost in translation...

Comment: @Karsten7. Neat+1 :)

Comment: @Karsten 7 Can you explain or comment your code a bit to understand it more

Comment: @Francisco See my update for an explanation of the code. For details on the use of [`Slot` (`#`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) in my function `fun` see this [Pure Functions tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: @ Karsten 7,Thanks, I will be attentive to your explanations, I am very interested as you solved the puzzle, the English did not acomplaña much, but google is my friend.Francisco

Comment: I understand all your explanation, except the last line fun2 / @% ,Francisco

Comment: @Francisco `/@` means [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) and `%` gives the last result ([`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html)). Hence `fun2 /@ %` was only there to calculate and show the differences for each connection. This line isn't necessary to solve the puzzle therefore I'll remove it from this post.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I have just used brute force but not as elegantly as Karsten 7 and I am too time poor to cull labeling that are just reflections etc. The graph layout just for visualization out of laziness but isomorphic to graph.

```
g = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 2, 4 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 
  4 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 3 <-> 7, 3 <-> 6, 2 <-> 6};
perm = Thread[Range[7] -> #] & /@ Permutations[Range[7]];
can = (g /. #) & /@ perm;
fun[u_] := Min[Abs[Subtract @@@ (List @@@ u)]] > 1
func[u_] := Count[Abs[Subtract @@@ (List @@@ u)], 1] == 1
```

Now,

```
ans = Pick[can, fun /@ can, True];
```

yields {}-> no solution.

However, if one edge allowed:

```
ans = Pick[can, func /@ can, True];
```

Visualizing:

```
Grid[Partition[
   Graph[#, VertexSize -> 0.7, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
       GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding", 
      VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold, 16], 
      VertexStyle -> White, ImageSize -> 150] & /@ ans, 9]];
```

[image]

Comment: @Francisco, I think there will be much better answers than mine...and I am not sure i completely answered, now reading rasher's comments...am quite time poor so just through the first thing that entered my head...consider other answers as they hopefully arise...but thank you for vote